# My png sprite is blinking in Andengine

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine

I am writing tower defense game on Android with Andengine.
I have a problem.
I am using 30-40 sprites.That sprites are 'enemy'.Their coordinates are changing every loop.(I am using TimerHandler) 
Enemys sprite's textures are transparent png image.
I am using galaxy s.When I tried my application, i haven't any problem.But i sent my application to my friend and he says enemys are random blinking flashing.One sprite is invisible and after little time, it is visible.Then another sprite is invisible and after little time, it is visible.

png file : http://nafiz.in/yerSipasi.png

Texture load:

```
yaratiklar = new BitmapTextureAtlas(256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

kaplama = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(yaratiklar, this, "yerSipasi.png" , 0, 0);
```

And sprite:

```
Sprite Yaratik = new Sprite(-50,-50, kaplama);
```

When move

```
  scene.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(1/50f,true,new ITimerCallback()
    {                      
        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler)
        {
           ....
           .. for...
    Yaratik[i].setPosition(xNew, yNew);
  ...
 }
 });
```

I can't understand why.

Thanks for read.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why someone would name something `BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory`. I mean, maybe it is the best possible name, but something seems a bit awkward about that.

Comment: Your friends phone might just be really crappy, and unable to run your game at a decent framerate.

Comment: Other application(ex angry birds, robo defense) is worked him phone.

Answer (score 3):

Two things to try

Firstly, are your sprites set to blend properly - something like this?

```
myspite.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Secondly, try disabling EVBOs as some handsets have trouble with them

```
public Engine onLoadEngine() {
     camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
     EngineOptions eo = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
     eo.getRenderOptions().disableExtensionVertexBufferObjects();
     return new Engine(eo);

}
```

The latter solved a problem with 'bits' of sprites disappearing in my games - I've no idea if that could extend to entire sprites tho...

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are not using same regions for multiple sprites. I had this issue once and my problem was that I was using same region for multiple sprites.